# Temporalizar una acción de tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, date

Con el siguiente código:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('200x100')

mensaje = tk.Text(ventana, width=20, height=2)
mensaje.insert(1.0, 'Espero 10 segundos')
mensaje.pack()

time.sleep(10)
ventana.quit()

ventana.mainloop()
```

pretendo dejar el mensaje 10 segundos en pantalla antes de que la ventana se cierre sola. En lugar de eso, el programa espera los 10 segundos **antes de poner el mensaje**, el cual queda visible todo el tiempo después.

Evidentemente hay un detalle del funcionamiento de tkinter que no logro entender, pues me parece que estoy escribiendo los elementos en la secuencia en la que espero sucedan.

Answer (score 0):

#### ¿Por que NO usar time.sleep cuando trabajas con Tkinter?

NUNCA uses `time.sleep` en Tkinter. `time.sleep` "traba" el código y no permite la ejecución del mainloop. Esto ocasionaría los siguientes problemas:

- Como la ventana no procesa los eventos, en caso de que ocurra uno, el sistema operativo podría quejarse de que el programa no responde. En resumen, será imposible interactuar con ella.
- Durante ese tiempo no podrás hacer ningún cambio en la ventana.

#### Alternativa a time.sleep: after

Tkinter ofrece el método universal [after](https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/la-funcion-after-en-tkinter/), que nos permite programar que en x milisegundos una función se ejecute. Y, a diferencia de time.sleep, no detiene el mainloop de Tkinter, por lo que su uso no va a impedir que el usuario interactue con la ventana.

#### ventana.destroy es lo que buscas para cerrar la ventana.

No se bien por que `ventana.quit` pareciera no hacer nada (ni se bien su proposito). Es la primera vez que lo conozco. Lo unico que se es que probablemente lo que buscas sea `ventana.destroy()`, que elimina la ventana junto a sus widgets y termina el mainloop.

#### Solución

En base a estas cosas, la solución sería:

```
import tkinter as tk

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry('200x100')

def cerrar():
    ventana.destroy()

mensaje = tk.Text(ventana, width=20, height=2)
mensaje.insert(1.0, 'Espero 10 segundos')
mensaje.pack()

# 10000 milisegundos es 10 segundos
ventana.after(10000, cerrar)

ventana.mainloop()
```